# How to marshal nested attribute up to the schema?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-restful, flask-restplus

I have a project with articles having different prices depending on their location.

The `Article` and `ArticlePrice` models are as follow:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Article(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'article'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    prices = relationship("ArticlePrice")

class ArticlePrice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'article_prices'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("article.id"), nullable=False)
    location_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("location.id"), nullable=False)
    price = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    location = relationship('Location')
```

I don't want to return all the prices of an article to the client but just *his* location price. Such as he receives a JSON like:

```
{
  id: '',
  title: '',
  description: '',
  price: 0
}
```

So my schema looks like this now:

```
article = namespace.model('Article', {
    'id': fields.Integer(required=True),
    'title': fields.String(required=True),
    'description': fields.String(required=True),
    'price': fields.Integer(attribute=lambda x: x.prices[0].price), # This one works
})
```

**This is working fine** with a **lambda expression**, but in the documentation ([flask-restful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.6/fields.html#renaming-attributes) and [flask-restplus](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#renaming-attributes)) they talk about another way, but I can't make it work as follow:

```
'price': fields.Integer(attribute='prices[0].price') # This one doesn't work
```

What am I missing? Why is the last syntax not working? Did I misunderstand this syntax use?

Comment: did you try: (attribute='prices.0.price')

Comment: @smundlay Yes, didn't work either.

Comment: @Elfayer I'm late here but, there is an open issue [#91](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx/issues/91) on flask-restx and [#783](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/783) on flask-restplus, because of which `(attribute='prices.0.price')`  did not work!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example from the documentation (http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#renaming-attributes):

```
model = {
    'name': fields.String(attribute='people_list.0.person_dictionary.name'),
    'address': fields.String,
}
```

So just replace `[0]` by `.0.`